# Can't link Twitter with Satellizer.js

Tags: javascript, twitter, oauth, oauth-2.0, satellizer

The Facebook, Google and Yahoo login for `satellizer.js` was pretty straight forward. All I had to do was create apps with their respective API's, configure them with my homepage's URL. Then I added the app-ids to the `app.js` file:

```
$authProvider.facebook({
      clientId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    });
```

and lastly I added the app id and secret in the `config.js` file server-side.

I thought this would be the process with Twitter too, but their API keeps giving me an error saying

> Something is technically wrong. Thanks for noticing—we're going to fix
>   it up and have things back to normal soon.

and no additional information is given, which leaves me with finding the needle in the haystack.

Are there any additional measures that I need to take to make the Twitter authentication work?

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to set the right twitter secret and key.

I had the same problem until I rrealised that there was a space as the first character in the string of my twitter key.

This causes the same behavior you described

Comment: This fixed it after ages with no clear error, stupid copy/paste. +1